# How to add one custom column in Django built in auth_user table

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to add one status field in my django auth_user(Built In) table. I'm using the below code.

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Auth_user(AbstractBaseUser):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'status'
```

An in the settings.py I'm mentioning like this.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.Auth_user"
```

but the status field is not getting added in the table auth_user.Can somebody suggest how to add custom (column)field in Django in built table?

Answer (score 1):

change the name of your class
instead of class Auth_user() you should use class User()
and also dont forget to migrate.

for more information go through this code given below
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create migration (python manage.py makemigrations) and then migrate the db (python manage.py migrate) for changes in models to be reflected in the database.

Comment: I've done that but in this case the status is getting added but a new table is being created??..so is it creating a relationship between these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Extend the model as following -->

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'status'
```

then create the make `migrations` file and `migrate` db